# IntoIterator for larger slices

Tags: rust

I am trying to write an API server that uses `RegexSet`. Here is the code that uses it.

```
fn main() {
    let path_regex = regex::RegexSet = regex::RegexSet::new(&[
        r"^/api/$",
        ...
        r"^/logs/$",
        r"^/logs/(?P<logpath>[^/?#]*)$",
        r"^/version/$"
    ]).unwrap();
}
```

The slice passed to `RegexSet` has 346 elements. When I run this, I get

```
error[E0277]: `&[&str; 346]` is not an iterator
   --> src/server/mod.rs:650:60
    |
650 |         pub static ref GLOBAL_REGEX_SET: regex::RegexSet = regex::RegexSet::new(&[
    |                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `&[&str; 346]` is not an iterator
    |
    = help: the trait `std::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for `&[&str; 346]`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::IntoIterator` for `&[&str; 346]`
    = note: required by `server::paths::regex::RegexSet::new`
```

Looking at the documentation, `IntoIterator` has only been [implemented for arrays of size up to 32](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#impl-IntoIterator-40)

I tried to implement that trait, resulting in the error

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::iter::IntoIterator` for type `&[_; 346]`:
   --> src/server/mod.rs:651:5
    |
651 |     impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a [T; 346] {
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
            - impl<I> std::iter::IntoIterator for I
              where I: std::iter::Iterator;
    = note: upstream crates may add new impl of trait `std::iter::Iterator` for type `&[_; 346]` in future versions
```

How do I work around this?

Comment: Due to the current limitations of array types, only arrays up to length 32 implement a good portion of traits in the standard library, including `IntoIterator`. You can  turn that array into a slice (`[...].as_ref()`), which does implement `IntoIterator`.

Comment: Or via `&[/* elements */][..]`.